$s$ and $s+45$ have equal digital root
My dad had my little sister when he was $45$ years old. She is now $17$ and he is $62$. He noticed a peculiar property of their two ages: When they do the sum of the digits of their respective ages they obtain the same number, i.e.
$$17 \rightarrow 1 + 7 = 8 \quad \text{and} \quad 62\rightarrow 6+2 = 8.$$
It seems that this property has always been true since she was $1$ and he was $46 ~(\rightarrow 4 + 6 = 10 \rightarrow 1 + 0 = 1)$, and will continue to be true.
I feel that this is related to the fact that the digit root of my father's age was $9 ~(=4+5)$ when she was born. It seems that if my dad had been $27$ or $36$ the same property would have held. However, I struggle to prove it properly, any idea ?
EDIT: We can assume that my father and sister were born on the same day.

Note: Are you asking about digit sum, or digit root (taking digit sums repeatedly till you get a single digit)? Title says the former, writeup indicates the latter.

Also, are you assuming that they have the same birthdays? Is there a time when your dad is 46 but your sister is still 0?

The sum of digits? The sum of the digits of $46$ is $10$, not $1$. If you mean that you repeatedly sum the digits until you get a single one you should specify that.

@Calvin Lin Thank you for your comments, I edited the question. 1) Yes I meant the repeated digit sum. 2) Yes we can assume they have the same birthday.

Hint: The digital root of $a > 0 $ is equal to the remainder when $a$ is divided by 9 (with remainders from 1 to 9).

See the linked dupes on digital roots, and note that $,s+45\equiv s\pmod{!9}.\ \ $
